# Applying matrix commutation rules

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I want to symbolically replace occurences of matrix terms such as $zAB-zBA$ with $zC$, where $z$ is a number. This works as expected:

```mathematica
rule = q_.*(x_).(y_) - q_.*(y_).(x_) -> q*c;
z*a.b - z*b.a /. rule
(* Result: c z *)
```

The above also works if there is no `z`, yielding `c` as expected. However, it does not work with numeric coefficients:

```mathematica
2*a.b - 2*b.a /. rule
(* Result: 2 a.b - 2 b.a *)
(* Expected: 2 c *)
```

I tried changing the rule to `q_Number*(x_).(y_) - q_Number*(y_).(x_) -> q*c`, but it returns the same result.
I can use `FactorTerms` before applying the rules, but that will not work e.g. for the case `2*a.b - 2*b.a + 1`.

How do I handle the case with numeric coefficients?

Comment: Suppress evaluation of patterns enclosing the left side in HoldPattern and use :> instead -> . Coefficients with different signs are difficult to handle for numbers becaus of different classes, integers, reals, rationals, complexes. I usually use conditonal rules HoldPattern[ p_.*(x_) . (y_) + q_.*(y_) . (x_)] :> p*c /; p + q == 0

Comment: This asnwers my question, thank you. BTW, it seems to produce the expected result even without `HoldPattern`:  
`2 a.b - 2 b.a //. p_.*(x_) . (y_) + q_.*(y_) . (x_) :> p*c /; p + q == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a normal-ordering rule instead of trying to pattern-match a commutator directly.

With the commutator $\Gamma_{x,y}=x\cdot y-y\cdot x=-\Gamma_{y,x}$ we can replace $x\cdot y\to y\cdot x-\Gamma_{y,x}$ whenever $x\cdot y$ is not ordered,

```
rule = (x_) . (y_) /; !OrderedQ[{x, y}] -> y . x - Γ[y, x];
```

and thus end up only with ordered components and ordered commutators.

Try it out:

```
z*a.b - z*b.a /. rule // Expand
(*    z Γ[a, b]    *)

2*a.b - 2*b.a /. rule // Expand
(*    2 Γ[a, b]    *)

2*a.b - 3*b.a /. rule // Expand
(*    -a.b + 3 Γ[a, b]    *)
```

You can then substitute `Γ[a, b] -> c` if you like, of course.

Comment: Accepting this as a solution, although it might not be desirable to apply reordering to _every_ term in the expression. Given `z*a.b - z*b.a + c.a`, I'd rather `c.a` be left as is. Perhaps in that respect pattern-matching is more appropriate, but it depends on what one is trying to achieve.